# init-param in web.xml for Spring OncePerRequestFilter not getting set

Tags: spring, servlets, configuration, filter, web.xml

I have a Spring MVC app with Spring 3.2.5 that has a filter on it that makes a change to a request.  This filter has a parameter that I am trying to set via the init-param in web.xml.  I cannot seem to get the web.xml to set the value on my bean, and cannot figure out where it is getting stored (if it is at all) in the spring bean.  I have not added my filter bean to my context, but only to my web.xml.

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>
            ...
        </description>
        <param-name>allowMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

My filter code:

public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFilter.class);

protected String allowMethods;


@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Do filter stuff, and try printing allowMethods via the logger
}

/**
 * @return the allowMethods
 */
public String getAllowMethods()
{
    return allowMethods;
}

/**
 * @param allowMethods the allowMethods to set as a comma separated list
 * for request types.  For example, "GET" or "GET, PUT", or "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE"
 */
public void setAllowMethods(String allowMethods)
{
    logger.info("Setting CORS filter to allow cross-site scripting with methods: {}", allowMethods);
    this.allowMethods = allowMethods;
}
```

}

I do not see the setter message, the value is not stored in the filter configuration that Spring saves, and I cannot override any methods that look like they'll give me the information I want (they are declared **final**).

How do I get the init-param mapped to my filter.  Do I have to use the applicationContext to do it?  If so, what is the convention to do this with Spring?

Thanks

Comment: The `DelegatingFilterProxy` requires a bean registered in ApplicationContext (hence the delegation part). It doesn't do anything with the init-params as it expects the filter to be fully configured in the spring context.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, I guess.  My follow up question would be does it need to be in web.xml and the context config for Spring, or just the context configuration?

Comment: If you use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` you must configure the filter in your spring configuration. If you use the filter directly in your web.xml then it must be configured using init-params.